# Example of a function ($\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) which is continuous only at two point .

Tags: real-analysis

Example of a function ($\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$)  which is continuous only at two point and differentiable only at one of these points.

Comment: Is it a challenge ? :-)

Comment: I don't know the answer.

Comment: Try something like $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational, and $f(x)=x^2(1-x)$ when $x$ is rational.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0    \hfill & \text{ if $x$ is irrational} \\
      \hfill x \hfill & \text{ if $x$ is rational with $x<1/2$} \\
\hfill (x-1)^2 \hfill & \text{ if $x$ is rational with $x\geq 1/2$} \\
  \end{cases}$

Here f is continuous only at $x=0$ and $x=1$. Also, f is differentiable only at $x=1$.